# How to click on a part of an SVG within a website with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg, click

Javascript provides a method called `click()`.

This works for example:

```
<a id="a" href="index.htm">Click here</a>
```

and

```
document.getElementById("a").click();
```

---

But what about SVG-Elements?

```
<svg>
  <g id="a" .....></g>
</svg>
```

This won't work:

```
document.getElementById("a").click();
```

I can successfully select the g-Tag, but it has no click method:

> document.getElementById(...).click is not a function

Is it somehow possible to click an element within an SVG-Tag with Javascript?

Answer (score 4):

You can just create and dispatch the event manually e.g.

```
document.getElementById("a").dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

This is all the click() method does underneath the hood. It's just a convenience method.

This will work with any SVG element, including `<g>` elements.

Comment: Thanks. This works on a random website I tried (http://referencewebapp.qaautomation.net/svg.php). But somehow it does not work for the website I need it for.. No error. If I run it in the browser, it returns true but does not execute the click.

Answer (score 1):

use `dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))` if `.click()` is not working.
Please check the fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/mvqpg930/1/

Comment: Hmm... It says to click shapes in the g-element.. They are not containers... In my case, the g-element contains a text tag, a rect tag, a polygon tag... But none of these work: `document.querySelector("#a>rect").click();`, `document.querySelector("#a>text").click();`... The click()-Method does not seem to exist for those too...

Answer (score -1):

Not entirely sure whether JavaScript has an actual `click()` event (I do know it can be inserted as: `onclick()` in HTML). jQuery has a `click()` event. That said, I believe you have to add an `eventlistener` if you are using JavaScript and no jQuery.

```
document.getElementById("a").addEventListener('click', function() {
     //do something
});
```

Comment: I use the click() for a Selenium UI test workaround for Safari.. Adding an event listener works (does not fail), but clicking it then fails with the same exception for me..

Comment: As mentioned above, and maybe an edit to my answer would  do the trick: <g> itself cannot be clicked.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried the "onclick" directly on the HTML?

I know it's brutal, but did it works?

```
<svg>
  <g id="a" onclick="your code here"  .....></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi, I want the Javascript code to click the element. I don't want to define what happens when it is clicked.